# How to transfer control from one Project to another project in a Singe Solution ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have two projects.One project is build in MVC asp.net and the other project is simple a Form Based Asp.net website.
Now I want when i click on a link in Form Based Asp.net Website it should transfer the control  from that website to MVC asp.net website and also i want to share sessions which are genrated in Form Based Asp.net Website.

Please Help.....thanx in advance

Comment: what do you mean by transfer the control from site A to site B ? Server.transfer() ?

Comment: I have added two Projects in Visual Studio. Now if Suppose I click on a link button in Form based Website it should get redirected to that MVC asp.net Project?

Comment: are these 2 projects deployed under same domain ?

Comment: Yes.....i want to deploy them under same domain name only

Comment: check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx

Comment: Can you tell me how would i Redirect the page.like i tried server.trasfer() but its not working...so can you tell me some code?

Comment: in your controler return Redirect("your web form page url")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your redirect question

In your MVC controller

```
if (viewModel.toOldForm)
{ 
   return Redirect("your form URL");
}
else 
{
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

In your form based app

```
Response.Redirect("your MVC URL");
```

using a link button:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```